# How to Add slide left and slide right animation to uib-tab tag in angularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, animate.css

I am trying to add slide left and slide right animation to my tabs, i want the animation in below fashion.

if I am on tab1 and click on tab 2, then tab 2 should slide from right; same when I am on tab 2 and if i click tab3;

if I am on tab 3 and I click tab 2, then tab 2 should slide from left; same when I am on tab 2 and click tab 1;

on page load I want tab 1 to slide from left.

some thing like Book pages transition;

I have added animation which slides the tabs in only 1 direction i.e using Animate.css classes. `animate slideInLeft` and `animate slideInRight`

Below is the sample code.

**HTML**

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab heading="Basic User Details">
      <h4 class="animated slideInLeft">Basic User Details</h4>
    </uib-tab>

    <uib-tab heading="Question and Answers">
      <h4 class="animated slideInLeft">Question and Answers</h4>
    </uib-tab>

    <uib-tab heading="Additional User Details">
      <h4 class="animated slideInLeft">Additional User Details</h4>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

I want to dynamically change the class of tab 1 and 2 depending on which tab is active.